# Restoring data from a failed and possibly partly overwritten mdadm raid1

Tags: mdadm, raid1, luks

I have a failing hard disk (let's call it `sda`) which contains, among other things, a 1.5 TB partition (let's call it `sda3`). There is another disk (`sdb`), which has a 1.5 TB partition (`sdb1`) as well. Both used to be part of an mdadm level 1 RAID using metadata version 1.2. Inside this RAID partition (let's call id `md5`), there is a LUKS encryption container (let's call it `md5_uncrypted`). This container should contain an ext4 partition.

At some place in time around August 10, 2012, I somehow restarted the RAID array with `sdb1` missing and didn't even notice that. When I wanted to replace the RAID yesterday (three months later), I started copying data from `sdb1` until I realized that it was out of date. So I took a look at the old `sda3`. By mistake, I ran `mdadm --create` instead of `mdadm --assemble` to restart `md5` with only `sda3` available. Accordingly, I ignored all warnings and let `mdadm --create` continue. `cryptsetup` didn't like the content of the new RAID. I didn't actually think `mdadm --create` would corrupt data if the same metadata version is used? Well, apparently it did.

I compared the first 20 MB of `sda3` and `sdb1` and noticed that they are equal starting at about 8 MB. So I copied the first 8 MB of `sdb1` to `sda3` (I have a backup of the old first 20 MB of `sda3`) and tried to assemble `md5` (with only a single drive, `sda3`). Unfortunately, this gave me an error:

```
failed to add /dev/sdb1: Invalid argument
```

I also tried using the LUKS header from `sdb1` on a freshly `mdadm --create`d `sda3`, which `cryptsetup` happily did (of course), but it contained garbage.

My question is: Is there any chance to restore at least some of the data from `sda3`? Since I have the state from three months ago, everything helps, even just a list of files, or a list of files with modification dates.

**Edit:**

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1
         Magic : a92b4efc
       Version : 1.2
   Feature Map : 0x0
    Array UUID : 76a25475:70aa881c:dd30cc93:bbae03b7
          Name : ubuntu:0
 Creation Time : Fri Mar 16 20:52:16 2012
    Raid Level : raid1
  Raid Devices : 2

Avail Dev Size : 2930272256 (1397.26 GiB 1500.30 GB)
    Array Size : 1465129848 (1397.26 GiB 1500.29 GB)
 Used Dev Size : 2930259696 (1397.26 GiB 1500.29 GB)
   Data Offset : 2048 sectors
  Super Offset : 8 sectors
         State : clean
   Device UUID : b9012482:afa502cf:7794f4fb:2a0da196

   Update Time : Wed Nov 21 20:51:51 2012
      Checksum : 4e54a07 - correct
        Events : 15003


  Device Role : Active device 1
  Array State : .A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)

# mdadm --examine /dev/sda3
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 54ea031e:42367512:b6a8675b:91f2cb6f
           Name : willow:5  (local to host willow)
  Creation Time : Wed Nov 21 18:03:35 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 2929999872 (1397.13 GiB 1500.16 GB)
     Array Size : 1464999744 (1397.13 GiB 1500.16 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2929999488 (1397.13 GiB 1500.16 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 93c70c36:3cc540a5:13817695:bd4f327c

    Update Time : Wed Nov 21 18:03:35 2012
       Checksum : 321ddb3e - correct
         Events : 0


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if you have a spare HDD I would strongly advise to mirror sda3 and just work with the mirror.

mdadm --create with the same options shouldn't corrupt data unless defaults of unspecified options are changed between the version which initially created the array and the current version.

Did you compare the superblocks on sdb1 and sda3 with mdadm --examine?

Unless you've added/changed/removed keys the luks header should be identical. Have you tried to restore luksHeaderBackup from the sdb1 array to the created array on sda3?

Different offsets of the luks header {'L','U','K','S',0xba,0xbe} on sdb1 and sda3 would explain garbage in luks volume.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I think, version 3.2.3-2 created the array, and right now I'm on 3.2.5-3, so there's probably no change in default values involved. As for comparing the superblocks – the original `sda3` superblock is lost, so which should I compare against? I will have a look at the luks header positions; I didn't change the keys in the last three months on that system.

Comment: Unfortunately, both LUKS headers start at exactly 1MB.

Comment: And have exactly the same content. I wonder if I can't just take everything from the LUKS header to the end and try to luksOpen it? I would probably need to correct LUKS' payload offset (which currently has 1936220465 if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: compare the old superblock from sdb1 against a newly created on sda3 and the one you made during the initial assemble/create mishap.

Comment: 1MB from the start of the partition I presume? And directly at the start of the raid array? 1936220465 sounds wrong for the payload offset, that would be beyond the end of HDD

Comment: 1 MB from the start of the physical partition. When building the raid on `sdb1`, the LUKS header is at 0, but the `sda3` RAID has only garbage and no LUKS header. I guess I should investigate a bit more what kind of garbage that is and whether it is somewhere on this partition.

Comment: There is a luks header 1MB from the start of the physical sda3 partition but not at the start of the raid array of sda3? The raid layout has to be different then. Is the start of the sda3 raid array before or after the LUKS header on the physical sda3 partition?

Comment: I posted the two `mdadm --examine` headers. There's definitely a different, wrong data offset in the new `sda3` header. So, I figured I should ignore the mdadm stuff and just take everything from `sda3` after the first 1 MB (so from the start of the LUKS header on). I tested that with the first 20 MB, and cryptsetup happily uncrypted it, and fsck.ext4 thinks the uncrypted stuff is an ext4. So, I think we're done here. Thank you very much for guiding me through this process!